# Customizing call back for ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture() to get passed uri as well

Tags: android, callback, android-camera-intent, onactivityresult, registerforactivityresult

The following are the methods i have declared for capturing image from Android 11 version supporting app. I want to cutomize the call back to get the input uri, instead of just getting a boolean status.

As of now the following is methods, which are working fine.

```
private final ActivityResultLauncher<Uri> takePicture =
                registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture(), this::onTakePictureResult);

private void android11Capture() {
    try {
        Context ctx = requireContext();
        String authorities = ctx.getPackageName() + AUTHORITY_SUFFIX;
         Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(ctx, authorities, createImageFile());
        takePicture.launch(imageUri);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void onTakePictureResult(boolean success) {
    showToast(success + "");
    if (success) {
        cropImage();
    } else {
        showToast("taking picture failed");
    }
}
```

I just want to customize the method onTakePictureResult. Such that i can get the passed imageUri as well in call back)

```
public void onTakePictureResult(boolean success, Uri imageUri) {
    showToast(success + "");
    if (success) {
        cropImage(imageUri);
    } else {
        showToast("taking picture failed");
    }
}
```

Note: Since i don't want to create a separate variable for this. I want to know is this possible ?

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: Did you [read the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#launch): "Note: Since your process and activity can be destroyed between when you call launch() and when the onActivityResult() callback is triggered, any additional state needed to handle the result must be saved and restored separately from these APIs."

Comment: Thanks for the link. I shall go through the documentation .